# Is there a news feed for new Steam demos?

Tags: steam

Steam publishes a [news feed for "general Steam news"](http://store.steampowered.com/feeds/news.xml) and a [news feed for new releases](http://store.steampowered.com/feeds/newreleases.xml); however, I've noticed I often manually check out the [demos page](http://store.steampowered.com/freestuff/demos/), looking for new demos.

Is there any news feed for that page, updating with new game demos as they are released?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think there is a feed, but it could be useful, so I just created one using **Feed43** free service.

Here it is, for your needs: http://feed43.com/recent-steam-demos.xml

Let me know if it works for you, or if it can be improved in some way.